# How to create a subdomain for sending and receiving email with OVH using Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I am trying to create an email with a subdomain as follow : `@subdomain.domain.com`.

The domain provider is OVH and Google Product manages my emails.

So far I only have my domain. Can you please guide me through the steps to create a subdomain on which I can send and receive emails ?

Do I need to create first a subdomain on OVH and after verify identity on google? If so, how to proceed?

Thank you for your help
 [image]

Comment: why do you want the email to go to the subdomain?

Comment: because I need to create mailing campaign and I don't want to affect my domain reputation